# Import polygons with predefined coordinates

Tags: import, vertices

Let's presume I have a file with polygons vertices coordinates in any format. I need to import the polygons into Blender. Can it be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the Wavefront .obj format. As it's written in ASCII, it's fairly easy to generate.

A simple introduction to the specification of this format is as follows:

```
#This is a comment

o Object      #Defines an object named Object
              #All the vertices, edges and faces below this belong to this object
              #Until another object is declared

v 1.0 1.0 1.0 #Defines a vertex at the XYZ coordinates 1, 1, 1 
              #and adds it to the list of vertices, like an array (starts at index 1)

f 1 2 3 4     #Creates a face defined by the indexes 1, 2, 3 and for
              #Which refer to the vertices in the list above
```

.
For the complete specification, please see [this page](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec).

To import it, you can just go to the `3D View` header, press `File`, then `Import`, and then `Wavefront (.obj)`. This will bring you to the file browser, where you can choose your file, and in the bottom left corner, choose some extra settings.