# Rendering an external smoke/fluid simulation in Blender

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I have done a smoke(fluid) simulation in a C++ framework using Navier-Stokes.
Let us say it is for 100 time steps.
For every time-step I have the smoke concentration.That is, I have a scalar value for every cell on a grid(say, of a resolution of 128*128 - in x and y directions). It can be 3D also. So, I have stored these values in an array in C++.

I wish to render it in Blender. Can anyone please guide me?

I think if we have obj files for every frame, the rest can be done with Python integration in Blender.
But, how to create the obj files from the array values I have(which I mentioned earlier) ?

Comment: Welcome! :) You can use c++ (don't know if there is a lib) to generate an obj sequence (frame_001, frame_002 ...) and simply batch import it into Blender. related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/batch-import-wavefront-obj For generating objs, see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21737/import-polygons-with-predefined-coordinates/21742#21742